# Android - alternate resources for specific manufacturer

Tags: android, layout, view, gradient

I'd like to have alternate **resources for specific Android phone manufacturers like: Samsung, LG**, etc. 
The problem is that some of the LG phones can't inflate gradients properly and so I'd like to provide an alternative resource just for this brand.

```
Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
```

where line 14: is a vector path with gradient.

You can find information on how to provide different resource files based on language, screen size, touch-screen type and so on [here](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/resources/android_resources-i18n_AlternateResources.html).

I can't find any information on **whether you can differentiate layouts based on manufacturer string** or not.

Ideally, this would be something similar to:

```
res/
   drawable-qwerty/
   drawable-man_lg/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find any information on whether you can differentiate layouts based on manufacturer string or not.

There is no option for this in the resource system, sorry. Java/Kotlin code can make decisions based on `Build` values, but resources cannot.